# Property 'onboarding' does not exist on type '{ theme: { onboarding: boolean; }; }'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

```
import React from "react"; 
import {styled, Paper} from "@material-ui/core";

const StyledPaper = styled(Paper)<{onboarding: boolean}>(({onboarding, theme}) => ({ ... }));
```

Throwing the error **Property 'onboarding' does not exist on type '{ theme: { onboarding: boolean; }; }'**.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OboZY.png)

Comment: Looks like you have material 4 version but you are trying to use material 5 syntax.

Comment: You may want to take help from - https://v4.mui.com/guides/interoperability/#styled-components